# Center a ion-button using Ionic framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, alignment

It's my first time with Ionic framework. I want to center a "ion-button", how I can do it? This is my view:

[image]

This is my html code:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h3>Effettua l'accesso</h3>

  <p>
    Esegui il login oppure procedi come utente non registrato. Clicca in alto a sinistra per vedere il menu.
  </p>

  <form ng-submit="submitLogin()">
   <tr>  
       <td>Email</td>
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="prodescForm.description"/></td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Password</td>  
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="prodescForm.registerDiscount" /></td>                 
  </tr> 
  <button ion-button>Login</button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

note: I just changed "page1.html" of a ionic project with sidebar.
How I can center this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd recommend against using `table`s for the layout of your form. The recommended way to do this would be with `div` or similar elements.

However, if you absolutely want to use a `table`, be sure to use it correctly. This would mean adding all the necessary `table`-related tags to make it a valid table. In this case wrapping it in a `<table>` should be enough.

Then apply some additional CSS to center the button in a table row. In the example below a `colspan='2'` to make the column extend the full width of the `tr`, then a class which applied a `text-align: center`.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

td.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form ng-submit="submitLogin()">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="prodescForm.description" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="prodescForm.registerDiscount" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class='centered'>
        <button ion-button>Login</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: However, why div is better than table?

Comment: I'll refer you to the excellent discussions on this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html).